# What is a limited estimator?

Tags: terminology

I'm reading [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1038/s41467-020-18035-1) where, on pp 3 of the pdf, the authors write (emphasis added):

"As the fitted two-component model is a *limited estimator* to classify bound/unbound sites, we additionally calculated null distributions of randomized corrected footprints."

Is this a formally defined term, or a synonym for a more common term (maybe biased estimator)? A google search turns up a few more uses, but no definitions as far as I can tell, and I'm not knowledgeable enough to pick it up from context alone.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community Hello bot, chances are you can't understand me, but I think the question is about as clear as a question can be. (I'm writing this to tell the thread opener to not worry too much about this... unfortunately I don't know the answer.)

Comment: @ChristianHennig Thanks, I was worried I'd done something wrong!